# Normalised Floating point representation

Tags: floating-point, binary, twos-complement

I'm trying to help someone out with some homework and I'm getting erroneous answers.

The question is this:

> Represent 〖-0.109375〗_10 in normalized floating point representation
>   having a 5-bit fractional two’s complement mantissa and a 3-bit
>   integer two’s complement exponent.

I have written the following notes:

Let’s work out the answer to the question:
〖-0.109375〗_10
Step 1: Convert to binary.

0   0. 0    0   0   1   1   1   0   0

〖-(00.00011100)〗_2

Step 2: Multiply by 1 (2^0)
〖-(00.00011100)〗_2  x 2^0

Step 3: Shift to make mantissa whole number
We need to make 6 shifts to the left
Why?
Because we have 0.000111
Shift 1 = 00.00111
Shift 2 = 000.0111
Shift 3 = 0000.111
Shift 4 = 00001.11
Shift 5 = 000011.1
Shift 6 = 0000111

Therefore we get,
-(〖111〗_2) x 2^(-6)

Step 4: Convert mantissa. In this question we were requested to convert to two’s complement (5-bit fractional)
Therefore we need to convert – 111 to two’s complement and make this 5 bit

Step A: Convert to one’s complement (5 bit)
-00111 = 11000
Step B: Convert to two’s complement (5-bit)
11000 +
00001
= 〖11001〗_2

Step 5: Convert exponent top 2-bit two’s complement
2^(-6)

Therefore we need to convert -6 to binary (two’s complement)
Step A: Convert to binary 
1   1   0

Step B: Convert to one’s complement (3-bit)
110 = 001

Step C: Convert to two’s complement
010

The answer is then,
〖11001      010〗_2

As you can see, 2^-6 seems wrong for a 3-bit two's complement.

Can anyone point out what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Usually the significand (not mantissa<sup>1</sup>) is shifted so the most significant one bit is in a certain position, not so the significand is an integer. The IEEE 754 format normalizes the significand to 1.*ddd…d*, where each *d* is a digit in the base being used.

Shifting your value to move the first one bit to that position yields an exponent of –4. You would have –1.110<sub>2</sub>•2<sup>–4</sup>. To represent the significand in two’s complement, we add another bit on the left, producing –01.110<sub>2</sub>•2<sup>–4</sup>, and then apply the negation to yield 10.010 for the significand and 100 for the exponent.

However, there can be some variation on details. Is the significand normalized to 1.*ddd…d* or .1*ddd…d*? Is the significand five bits before adding a sign bit or after?

Do you have examples of values with known representations in this format? Or more details about the format?

---

<sup>1</sup>“Significand” is the preferred term. A significand is linear; a mantissa is logarithmic.

Comment: The requirement that the significand be two's complement may change this a bit. The leading bit has to have the possibility of being 0 to indicate positive. IEEE 754, of course, uses an unsigned significand and a separate sign bit.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: The answer already includes provision for two’s complement. Note the sentence “To represent the significand in two’s complement, we add another bit on the left…”